Passing a variable to window.open method
I'm trying to pass a variable to window.open() method. I would like to use that passed variable to the opened html file.
<script>
  var value = document.getElementById("oper").value;
  const Gobtn = document.getElementById("Go");

  Gobtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.open("calculate.html", value);
  });
</script>

I'm trying to open "calculate.html" and use the content of the variable named "value" in the "calculate.html" file. Thanks.

Pass it as a query string value.

to passing variables i suggest you to look at this similar question:
javascript : sending custom parameters with window.open() but its not working
The second parameter is a target attribute, look at this documentation:
Window open()

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
